# Question about symmetric block design and Hadamard matrix

Tags: combinatorial-designs

I stock in middle of proving that if $A$ is matrix of symmetric block design and $B = 2A - J$ that $J$ is ones matrix then B is a Hadamard matrix if and only if $v = 4(k-\lambda)$. I need to prove that
$$
\begin{equation*}
-2(JA)^T - 2JA + J^2 = (-4k + v)J
\end{equation*}
$$
is there any helpful hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjacency matrix of a symmetric block design satisfies $AA^T=(r-\lambda)I+\lambda J$ and $JA=AJ=kJ$. An Hadamard matrix $H$ satisfies $HH^T=nI$. 
So now let us count $BB^T$:
$$
BB^T=(2A-J)(2A-J)^T=4AA^T-2AJ-2JA+JJ^T=4((r-\lambda)I+\lambda J)-4kJ+vJ.
$$
Thus, $BB^T=4(r-\lambda)I+[4(\lambda-k)+v]J$. Therefore $B$ is Hadamard if the coefficient of $J$ is zero, hence $v=4(k-\lambda)$.